# One page of my website related to the db doesn't work UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I just created this website https://m-landscape.herokuapp.com/ using node.js and mongoDB, but the gallery route that uses the db doesn't load at all even though it loads perfectly when I run it on the terminal. How can I solve this?

This is what I get when I type heroku logs:

```
2017-08-12T05:15:14.128733+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=f5354a5c-df9b-469b-a69f-a2743e2922d9 fwd="156.205.87.209" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=9046 protocol=https
2017-08-12T05:15:26.637696+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/landscapes" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=cbeb8fa7-bd03-47c0-aa76-c8e1cfc70c40 fwd="156.205.87.209" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=27ms status=304 bytes=152 protocol=https
2017-08-12T05:15:26.846189+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=18ec3a58-3528-49c8-af99-4f7bc28e810a fwd="156.205.87.209" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2017-08-12T05:15:58.831552+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/gallery" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=c15d0000-166c-4705-ad1a-116e6985744c fwd="156.205.87.209" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2017-08-12T05:16:19.533667+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/landscapes" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=c3e8adba-f14a-4cc3-8106-58215e3364d3 fwd="156.205.87.209" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=152 protocol=https
2017-08-12T05:16:19.727921+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=6024122e-8f8b-49e5-9392-1e1591a526d1 fwd="156.205.87.209" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2017-08-12T05:16:19.883184+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=070b690a-5701-4e66-9432-b065f272a983 fwd="156.205.87.209" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2017-08-12T05:16:22.930272+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/about" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=c0ca728f-bad6-4d4a-84d3-cb57f77908f9 fwd="156.205.87.209" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=3960 protocol=https
2017-08-12T05:16:23.155574+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=2d97c8dd-12e4-4d27-a889-2a80309eefc7 fwd="156.205.87.209" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2017-08-12T05:16:24.462197+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/gallery" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=5048db82-f696-4df2-9bc0-cbb913e33b9e fwd="156.205.87.209" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30003ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2017-08-12T05:16:26.383545+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/contact" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=b9c3c474-690f-49b4-a47b-c75f1e4d2703 fwd="156.205.87.209" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=43ms status=200 bytes=4389 protocol=https
2017-08-12T05:16:26.568909+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/carousel.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=91ce952f-1e70-4772-8d8d-2cb160d476ea fwd="156.205.87.209" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=1081 protocol=https
2017-08-12T05:16:26.571180+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=ab6ba94b-257c-4551-a666-68f388c41883 fwd="156.205.87.209" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2017-08-12T05:16:26.724769+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=56143662-9bfa-4691-b805-057cf1ba2bbf fwd="156.205.87.209" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2017-08-12T05:16:28.616171+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/landscapes" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=16ffaef7-2cdc-451b-9664-fee284f09168 fwd="156.205.87.209" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=152 protocol=https
2017-08-12T05:16:28.839862+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=1935e544-9a9f-4877-8dfb-6b04584c14dc fwd="156.205.87.209" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2017-08-12T05:16:28.809192+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=cd2f0e1a-7ce8-436d-b375-09064fe9a965 fwd="156.205.87.209" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2017-08-12T05:16:36.494340+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=8fd57def-1c51-40eb-b6e0-70a889eb2ba3 fwd="156.205.87.209" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2017-08-12T05:51:35.947070+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-08-12T05:51:35.947708+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-08-12T05:51:36.511865+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-08-12T05:51:36.997605+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2017-08-12T06:38:52.403440+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2017-08-12T06:38:52.403705+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2017-08-12T06:38:55.933091+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-08-12T06:38:55.933104+00:00 app[web.1]: > mlandscape@1.0.0 start /app
2017-08-12T06:38:55.933105+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2017-08-12T06:38:55.933105+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-08-12T06:38:56.820635+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:17) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
2017-08-12T06:38:56.805440+00:00 app[web.1]: Server Has started!
2017-08-12T06:38:57.172006+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-08-12T06:38:57.508778+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=7dfafe17-7ad1-4661-965f-a9619d81f9ac fwd="106.51.44.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=31ms status=200 bytes=1368 protocol=https
2017-08-12T06:38:57.767218+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/landing.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=2ccf85d4-a4c1-4e46-98bb-e36d8367fc4d fwd="106.51.44.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=3019 protocol=https
2017-08-12T06:39:00.017724+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=d42c4bc2-05b0-4ab6-93ba-f33e44ca2a89 fwd="106.51.44.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=394 protocol=https
2017-08-12T06:39:03.547711+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/landscapes" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=f65b688e-e049-426a-9023-be3d2856ec3b fwd="106.51.44.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=4843 protocol=https
2017-08-12T06:39:03.829895+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=189778ef-7c68-4a6f-9351-90a230bbccf1 fwd="106.51.44.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=9046 protocol=https
2017-08-12T06:39:04.300052+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=9f1a9599-c049-4225-84a4-e9f4d26cf7b3 fwd="106.51.44.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=643 protocol=https
2017-08-12T06:39:43.363816+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/gallery" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=b4e12d06-9031-4752-bcf3-cc06fe514d48 fwd="106.51.44.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30002ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2017-08-12T06:40:02.177981+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/gallery" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=e661f8e4-5adb-43e9-8849-5abba31aa383 fwd="106.51.44.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2017-08-12T06:40:08.415934+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/about" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=43bd30cd-24fc-4dd8-8983-c430b7bb4e7c fwd="106.51.44.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=21ms status=200 bytes=3960 protocol=https
2017-08-12T06:40:08.876406+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=3091b383-e341-4b41-b678-9329cf03af0c fwd="106.51.44.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2017-08-12T06:40:08.984804+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=9761b955-8efa-48ce-bea7-1ead860c9fd8 fwd="106.51.44.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2017-08-12T06:40:20.964435+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=1a61802e-8247-4804-8d2d-d1466f72b52d fwd="106.51.44.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2017-08-12T06:40:20.970408+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/carousel.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=2ca57b4a-3694-4d1e-9591-57a658a2cf5b fwd="106.51.44.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=1081 protocol=https
2017-08-12T06:40:21.223340+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=16d6b9fc-b206-4bdb-b444-0a1f9a66d73f fwd="106.51.44.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2017-08-12T06:41:10.883534+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=76ccb562-c56d-424d-afa7-9ddf0ec1bcb2 fwd="106.51.44.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=151 protocol=https
2017-08-12T06:41:11.231218+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/landing.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=71f42453-b548-4f4c-a8f5-3c76834070e7 fwd="106.51.44.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2017-08-12T06:41:17.521008+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/landing.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=dcb8bed6-9837-456b-a57b-75a09fdc9e45 fwd="106.51.44.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2017-08-12T07:01:36.159161+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=0f3d182d-6030-4b49-8a1c-b8b653f89468 fwd="47.157.80.30" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=1368 protocol=https
2017-08-12T07:01:36.261814+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/landing.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=797471f0-84b2-4412-a972-05cabe0cb5fb fwd="47.157.80.30" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=3019 protocol=https
2017-08-12T07:01:36.652817+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=81de5fa8-a3a4-4ed3-99a9-80cf948297a3 fwd="47.157.80.30" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=394 protocol=https
2017-08-12T07:01:40.512549+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=2eb8080a-c715-4f03-94fc-e5ae917dac4f fwd="47.157.80.30" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=9046 protocol=https
2017-08-12T07:01:40.412190+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/landscapes" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=88f74ab0-eba8-477c-8d86-8793561592ec fwd="47.157.80.30" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=4843 protocol=https
2017-08-12T07:01:40.593098+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=fefa455e-7694-41a1-a112-bf4db046486f fwd="47.157.80.30" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=643 protocol=https
2017-08-12T07:01:48.798622+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/contact" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=d5396f98-360e-46c0-b2d6-7bf8181ef06b fwd="47.157.80.30" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=4389 protocol=https
2017-08-12T07:01:48.888013+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=e6c6a956-2be6-401c-90f5-a62bf07e8d3b fwd="47.157.80.30" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2017-08-12T07:01:49.036670+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=4923d962-d176-47e6-ac5c-00155c6af993 fwd="47.157.80.30" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2017-08-12T07:01:48.965879+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/carousel.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=724bf8ec-9e4f-4238-b88f-5796f26f1a62 fwd="47.157.80.30" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=1081 protocol=https
2017-08-12T07:38:08.262854+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-08-12T07:38:08.263608+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-08-12T07:38:08.919893+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-08-12T07:38:09.065149+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2017-08-12T09:52:59.211302+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2017-08-12T09:52:59.211519+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2017-08-12T09:53:00.859568+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-08-12T09:53:03.395411+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-08-12T09:53:03.395432+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2017-08-12T09:53:03.395431+00:00 app[web.1]: > mlandscape@1.0.0 start /app
2017-08-12T09:53:03.395433+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-08-12T09:53:04.061041+00:00 app[web.1]: Server Has started!
2017-08-12T09:53:04.071270+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:17) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
2017-08-12T09:53:04.479277+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-08-12T09:53:05.293715+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=9b313b6e-57ab-4fb1-be59-4aab4dee39fc fwd="62.143.18.213" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=29ms status=200 bytes=1368 protocol=https
2017-08-12T09:53:05.479942+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/landing.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=89fc8125-a304-4a9d-a638-825d6975f724 fwd="62.143.18.213" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=3019 protocol=https
2017-08-12T09:53:06.171863+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=4d420621-0012-4368-80a9-54ab33827afa fwd="62.143.18.213" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=404 bytes=394 protocol=https
2017-08-12T09:53:07.765206+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/landscapes" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=f06fc16f-00b9-4415-89e5-3722d12fa5b7 fwd="62.143.18.213" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=4843 protocol=https
2017-08-12T09:53:08.024507+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=d9a59713-c3e0-4071-884c-94b1b38c62a1 fwd="62.143.18.213" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=9046 protocol=https
2017-08-12T09:53:08.169819+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=2fdc9b30-8edb-40b3-b9ba-6ed40026cca9 fwd="62.143.18.213" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=643 protocol=https
2017-08-12T09:53:43.130952+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/gallery" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=ff4184c2-37d7-4b5d-be06-ba8492c2ab09 fwd="62.143.18.213" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2017-08-12T09:53:47.822008+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/gallery" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=9b8caefa-90d5-4002-94d2-f4205b755a26 fwd="62.143.18.213" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2017-08-12T10:09:05.250236+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/landscapes" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=dd726556-be36-44f8-88d3-eb0f26950c08 fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=4843 protocol=http
2017-08-12T10:09:05.551041+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=e30d6674-7391-4b5b-a089-00eade149f6b fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=9046 protocol=http
2017-08-12T10:09:05.558471+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=b01cec18-1e66-401d-ad6e-8c55bf42a261 fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=643 protocol=http
2017-08-12T10:09:07.812358+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=d1eacd19-ca82-4d77-a0c2-87c5df636d1d fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=394 protocol=http
2017-08-12T10:09:14.011958+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/landscapes" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=fe939fa0-0f57-4a83-a1ce-f76f29321386 fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=152 protocol=http
2017-08-12T10:09:14.255774+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=c2e19b70-a593-417d-b955-48e99e268a81 fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=http
2017-08-12T10:09:14.393196+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=f6b82373-a2e4-4af9-8b15-b051697181e6 fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=http
2017-08-12T10:09:40.658365+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/gallery" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=3db8b0f7-e518-4fc5-ac93-a128cd4f5034 fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
2017-08-12T10:33:44.761403+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/landscapes" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=671cfbb5-2dcc-4654-9476-8e5c3f4ede9f fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=152 protocol=https
2017-08-12T10:33:45.049112+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=66af43f9-704b-4d36-85e1-c421d7b82db5 fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2017-08-12T10:33:45.537451+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=4a018af5-c2ad-4b7b-a92e-c5f19ac70a1d fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2017-08-12T10:33:49.013666+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/about" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=b62edcb0-df94-4bd5-88b7-27b2a7616f86 fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=151 protocol=https
2017-08-12T10:33:49.241580+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=522e5742-aaf5-46ce-a793-25a02551530d fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2017-08-12T10:33:49.392113+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=5e55ed09-7177-408c-b150-bce9df17055e fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2017-08-12T10:33:53.489863+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/contact" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=64b4440b-2c71-463c-b9f0-35f9883b2c52 fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=152 protocol=https
2017-08-12T10:33:53.710792+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=55282896-9e14-44a6-bd60-238b4bf13130 fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2017-08-12T10:33:53.880755+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/carousel.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=9851b705-495e-4e19-aff9-fd0e2a12f925 fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2017-08-12T10:33:54.017119+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=2ead8f6f-c527-4efb-b493-f2c36b87339b fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2017-08-12T10:33:55.992789+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/landscapes" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=203e9a69-acdf-462f-9f15-cd1089d32911 fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=152 protocol=https
2017-08-12T10:33:56.162198+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.css" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=01ed69ca-a1ba-4b86-bfd4-3178ff5860e7 fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2017-08-12T10:33:56.190157+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.js" host=m-landscape.herokuapp.com request_id=7d17deb9-8c7e-471f-b84a-3854ed944628 fwd="160.160.128.160" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
```

This is my app.js code:

```js
var express    = require("express"),
    app        = express(),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    methodOverride = require("method-override"),
    Landscape      = require("./models/landscape"),
    seedDB         = require("./seeds"),
    mongoose   = require("mongoose");

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/m_landscape", {useMongoClient: true});

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
// Use method-override (We tell it what to look for(_method))
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

// tell express to serve the public directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
seedDB();

// ======
// ROUTES
// ======

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("landing");
});

app.get("/landscapes", function(req, res){
    res.render("landscapes");
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
    res.render("about");
});


app.get("/gallery", function(req, res){
    // Get all landscapes from DB
    Landscape.find({},function(err, allLandscapes){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }   else{
            res.render("gallery", {landscapes: allLandscapes});
        }
    });
});

app.get("/gallery/:id", function(req, res){
    // Find the campground with provided id
    Landscape.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundLandscape){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }   else{
            console.log(foundLandscape);
            // Render show template with that landscape
            res.render("show", {landscape: foundLandscape});
        }
    });
});

app.get("/contact", function(req, res){
    res.render("contact");
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Server Has started!");
});
```

........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

1. You should resolve your MongoDB connection issue:

> 2017-08-12T06:38:56.820635+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:17)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): MongoError: failed to connect to server
>   [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED
>   127.0.0.1:27017]

2. You need return response to client,, if MongoDB return error:

```js
app.get("/gallery", function(req, res){
    // Get all landscapes from DB
    Landscape.find({},function(err, allLandscapes){
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send({ error: err }); //added
            console.log(err);
        }   else{
            res.render("gallery", {landscapes: allLandscapes});
        }
    });
});

app.get("/gallery/:id", function(req, res){
    // Find the campground with provided id
    Landscape.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundLandscape){
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send({ error: err }); //added
            console.log(err);
        }   else{
            console.log(foundLandscape);
            // Render show template with that landscape
            res.render("show", {landscape: foundLandscape});
        }
    });
});
```